# Two onChange Events for One TextField is Not Executing Both onChange Events

Tags: reactjs, uitextfield, office-js, onchange, tsx

In the following code, I am trying to execute two onChange events for one TextField. I tried executing both onChange events separately, and they work fine. Why won't both my events run at the same time? When I combined them, only the "handleChange" event is executing, not the "_onChange" event. What am I doing wrong?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextField } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField';
import { Stack, IStackProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Stack';
export interface TestState {
  [key: string]: TestState[keyof TestState];
  descriptionVal: string;
  multiline: boolean;
}

export default class Test extends React.Component<{}, TestState> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      descriptionVal: "",
      multiline: false
    };

  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    const columnProps: Partial<IStackProps> = {
      tokens: { childrenGap: 15 },
      styles: { root: { width: 300 } },
    };

    return (
      <Stack horizontal tokens={{ childrenGap: 50 }} styles={{ root: { width: 650 } }}>

        <Stack {...columnProps}>
          <TextField
            label="Switches from single to multiline if more than 50 characters are entered"
            multiline={this.state.multiline}
            onChange={this.twoCalls}
            value={this.state["descriptionVal"]}
          />
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
    );
  }
  twoCalls = e => {
    {this.handleChange("descriptionVal")(e)}
    {this._onChange}
  }
  private _onChange = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, newText: string): void => {
    const newMultiline = newText.length > 50;
    if (newMultiline !== this.state.multiline) {
      console.log(ev);
      this.setState({ multiline: newMultiline });
    }
  };
    handleChange = (field: string) => (event: any) => {
    const value = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
    this.setState({ [field]: value });
  };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"twoCalls" needs to be like this

```
  twoCalls = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, newText: string): void => {
    this.handleChange("descriptionVal")(e);

    this._onChange(e, newText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have extra curly braces you don't need around your statements. Second, you're not actually invoking the second function, `this.function !== this.function()`. You should do something like this:

```
twoCalls = e => {
    this.handleChange("descriptionVal")(e);
    this._onChange(e);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jayce444 , thanks for the response! Where would I put this.function !== this.function()? And after adding this._onChange(e), it says it needs to include newText in the parameter. How do I inlcude newText in the parameter?

Comment: "Expected 2 arguments, but got 1."

Comment: No this: `this.function !== this.function()` wasn't actual code, it's just pseudocode showing you that referencing a function and _calling_ a function aren't the same thing. And for `this._onChange`, it looks like it expects a string as a second argument, so you pass it in when making the function call, e.g. `this._onChange(e, "some string here");`